# WinForms - how to save the combobox selection in the app's settings?

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, controls, application-settings

I have a combobox embedded in a toolstrip - a `ToolStripCombobox` instance.

The list of items is the list of values of an `enum`.

I'd like to be able to load/save the *selection* (One of the `Selected[Index|Item|Text|...]` properties, from/to the app's `Settings` "mechanism".

Ideally, I'd like to be able to do that from the designer.

Normally, hooking a control's property to a certain setting is done (in the designer) from the control's properties, under `(ApplicationSettings)` - but none of the `SelectedXXX` properties shows up in there.

FWIW, in the particular case of toostrip-bound combo-boxes, the actual `SelectedXXX` properties are actually found a bit deeper, at `toolStripComboInstance.ComboBox.SelectedXXX`.

What I have done so far is configure the binding in code:

```
m_runTypeCombo   //the toolstrip control
    .ComboBox    //the actual combobox
    .DataBindings.Add(
    new System.Windows.Forms.Binding(
        "SelectedItem", 
        global::JavaPad.Properties.Settings.Default, 
        "RunType", 
        true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged
    )
);
```

The above works, but I was hoping for something cleaner (i.e. designer-based). If the built-in `ToolStripCombobox` doesn't support this, is there a (simple) way to derive my own type from that, and expose the `SelectedXXX` properties in such a way that it works with the *Application Settings* infrastructure (and its support in the designer)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to wrap the TooltipComboBox in your own custom control, you can do it like this:

```
public class MyCombo : ToolStripComboBox
{
    [SettingsBindable(true)]
    public int SelectedIndex
    {
        get { return ComboBox.SelectedIndex; }
        set { ComboBox.SelectedIndex = value; }
    }


}
```

Note that I haven't tested this beyond confirming that I can add the control to the ToolStrip, and that I can select a property - You may need to add PropertyChanged Events to make it work fully.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a try.